# R conditional calculate date difference

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

I need to work out a fast way of conditionally finding the difference, in days, between two dates in a data table.  I managed to do it with an "ifelse" statement but it is slow on big objects, so my question, is there a faster, more elegant way of achieving the same, perhaps using data.table commands like ":=" or something.  Thx. J.

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

rm(list = ls())

a <- as.Date(c ("2021-09-27", "2019-10-30", "2021-09-05"))
b <- as.Date(c ("2020-06-14", "2019-09-15", "2020-09-23"))
c <- as.Date(c ("2022-07-12", "2020-09-23", "2021-06-19"))

new <- data.table(leave = a, start = b, end = c)

new$days <- ifelse (
    new$leave < new$end,
    new$leave - new$start,
    new$end - new$start)
```

So in words, when leaving date < end of period, subtract leave from start, however if leave >= end then subtract start from end, and give result back in a new column in days.

Comment: Try `data.table::fiflese()`. Get some info [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/fifelse.html)

Comment: Would it be quicker to do this?  `new[, days := pmin(leave, end) - start]`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `pmin()` function and data.table's assign operator `:=`

```
new[, days := as.numeric(pmin(leave, end)-start)]
```

Or you could assign it to all rows one way then chain off a subset:

```
new[, days := as.numeric(end - start)][leave < end, days := leave - start]
```

Or take advantage of `by` and the `.GRP` special character:

```
new[, days := list(leave-start, end-start)[.GRP], keyby=.(leave>=end)]
```

Comment: Hi @JimMaas - I added a third option here. If none of these meet the needs then let me know and I'll figure something out :)